# Cannot install SASS on macOS 10.14.5

Tags: ruby, sass

I trying to set up a development environment on a new machine. Ruby seems unhappy.

**sudo npm install ruby -g**

```
+ ruby@0.6.1
updated 1 package in 0.294s
```

**ruby -v**

```
ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin18]
```

**sudo gem install sass**

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sass:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.11.1/ext/ffi_c
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby -I /Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0 -r ./siteconf20190607-1543-ilb80e.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.11.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/extensions/universal-darwin-18/2.3.0/ffi-1.11.1/gem_make.out
```

**Yes** I have already installed command line tools

**xcode-select --install**

```
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
```

I have uninstalled and reinstalled ruby. What else can I try?

Comment: I noticed there are two (or three?) versions: 1. **npm ruby -v** `6.9.0` 2. **ruby -v** `ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin18]` 3. **npm list -g** `├─┬ ruby@0.6.1` 

Some sort of PATH issue?

Comment: `npm` is Node.js, not Ruby, so that version number is for the NPM package manager. It's the same regardless, like `npm whatever -v` is still 6.9.0 on current installs.

Comment: @tadman I see. Of course, Ruby is not a node package. I was blindly following instructions on another SO thread :S

Comment: That thread is just plain wrong if that's the advice given. Hope you're not too far astray. This can be annoying to get going, but once set up it's usually not that much fuss to keep it working.

Comment: @tadman I was using Ruby just for sass for many years on my old machine and that does not have 'rbenv' installed. Somehow that works ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This NPM package you've installed called `ruby`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ruby) is **not Ruby**, but instead just something with the same name. It's not going to help with your Ruby problems. NPM is exclusively for [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/).

To work with Ruby you'll want to install [`rbenv`](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv). Follow the instructions closely for ensuring your Path is set up properly.

This gives you a lot more flexibility, but most importantly the Ruby development headers that are missing from the default macOS supplied Ruby.

Pure-Ruby packages will work without development headers, but anything that has compiled extensions, like Nokogiri or apparently Ruby SASS, will require them. In that case `rbenv` has you covered.

Comment: With `rbenv` it's important to *not* use `sudo`, that can mess up your permissions. Normally you won't `gem install` either, but instead `bundle install`. Make sure you're using the correct `gem` command: `gem env` can show you which Ruby is being used and where things get installed.

Comment: Yeah, if you don't have Bundler available the first thing you need to do is install that. It's really the only thing you'd `gem install`, from that point forward `bundler install` using your `Gemfile`.

Comment: Don't `sudo gem install`, just `gem install`. If the permissions are messed up you need to fix it.

Comment: Yeah, you can also use `rbenv global 2.4.3` to set your default.

Comment: [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) solved the issue however bundler did not seem necessary. Having installed [rbenv via homebrew](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#homebrew-on-macos) and then having installed Ruby 2.4.3 I was then able to set `rbenv local 2.4.3` (also put this in `~/.bash_profile`) and then use `gem install sass` successfully.